# Error Exception Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

I moved my laravel application to a new hosting account and I have been getting this error since then

```
ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

The email validator bro I guess.

I don't know if anyone has experience this kind of issue after moving a laravel website.

Please help!

Comment: check the logs, particularly error logs, will tell you where the error is coming from

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem was caused by a change to the php new version. If you do not know which page caused this error, you can use the Symfony test. Maybe this link will help you:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/tests.html

Answer (score 20):

The PHP Version is indeed the problem.
On the previous host it was PHP 7.3 but the new one run 7.4 so it caused the problem.

Now I have downgraded to PHP 7.3.1 and the application now works fine.

Thanks so much.