# How to resolve l5-swagger issue -"Trying to access array offset on value of type bool" in php 7.4?

Tags: php, swagger, laravel-6, swagger-php, php-7.4

I was working on php version 7.2 but now upgrading to 7.4 gave an issue while generating l5-swagger. 
 I read this [stackoverflow qauestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831791/errorexception-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null) which is not working for me.

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
Regenerating docs

   ErrorException  : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

  at /home/smartmobe/Projects/defence-new/server/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/StaticAnalyser.php:37
    33|             if (empty($GLOBALS['swagger_opcache_warning'])) {
    34|                 $GLOBALS['swagger_opcache_warning'] = true;
    35|                 $status = opcache_get_status();
    36|                 $config = opcache_get_configuration();
  > 37|                 if ($status['opcache_enabled'] && $config['directives']['opcache.save_comments'] == false) {
    38|                     Logger::warning("php.ini \"opcache.save_comments = 0\" interferes with extracting annotations.\n[LINK] http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.save-comments");
    39|                 }
    40|             }
    41|         }

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()
      /home/smartmobe/Projects/defence-new/server/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/StaticAnalyser.php:37

  2   Swagger\StaticAnalyser::fromFile()
      /home/smartmobe/Projects/defence-new/server/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/functions.php:41

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Can you check that zircote/swagger-php has a version >= [3.0.3](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/pull/722)?

Comment: my current version for zircote/swagger-php is 2.0.14.

Answer (score 2):

zircote/swagger-php (the package in which your exception occurs) was updated to support PHP 7.4 in version [3.0.3](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/pull/722/files). If you're using Composer you can check the current version of the package in your project with `composer info zircote/swagger-php` and you can update it using `composer update`.

If `composer update` doesn't do the trick, you need to check that your `composer.json` allows for `darkaonline/l5-swagger` to have a version greater than 5.6.1 because it only started to support zircote/swagger-php:3.* from [5.6.2](https://packagist.org/packages/darkaonline/l5-swagger#5.6.2) upwards.

Comment: I currently have:

darkaonline/l5-swagger                6.0.3      Swagger integration to Laravel 5

Comment: I updated the composer to set:
"zircote/swagger-php":        "3.0.3",

Comment: Did you run `composer update`? So you shouldn't get exception anymore now.

Comment: composer update doesn't work and my current version for  "darkaonline/l5-swagger" is  "6.0.*". Following error is shown after updating: 

  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined function Swagger\scan()

  at /home/smartmobe/Projects/defence-new/server/vendor/darkaonline/l5-swagger/src/Generator.php:124

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel >= 8 and latest version of L5-Swagger you don't need to extend the route you need to add the web middleware in the `l5-swagger.php` config file (documentations/defaults/routes/middleware/api);

[image]